# Setting up multiple databases in Vagrant

Tags: replication, virtualisation

Currently I am using Vagrant 1.4.3 in-conjunction with VirtualBox running Unix (Centos) for my development server (using MariaDB).

I didn't setup the box myself (so my knowledge of setting this up is limited) I would basically like to do the following (if this is possible)...

Please note I can appreciate that a **full explanation** for doing this might be out of the scope of Stackoverflow. Essentially in the end i'd like to have a master-slave setup.

Essentially i'd like to:

- Run two databases on separate ports that run in a 'master-slave'
- This setup needs to run within my Vagrant setup

For instance lets say 'Database 1' has the port 3306 and will be the master, and 'Database 2' has the port 4406 will be the slave. I want any changes made made to Database 1 to automatically be 'pushed' to Database 2.

I've never had to do this before.. so bear with me please.

Any advice on the matter would be appreciated, I presume i'm not the only guy who is struggling with mysql-replication :)

If it helps - my current vagrant file looks like the following:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Config Github Settings
github_username = "ACMEINC"
github_repo     = "vagrant"
github_tag      = "0.11"
github_path     = "https://raw.github.com/#{github_username}/#{github_repo}/#{github_tag}/"

# Server Configuration

# Set a local private network IP address.
# See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network for explanation
# You can use the following IP ranges:
#   10.0.0.1    - 10.255.255.254
#   172.16.0.1  - 172.31.255.254
#   192.168.0.1 - 192.168.255.254
server_ip              = "192.168.30.10"

server_memory          = "4096" # MB
server_timezone        = "UTC"
server_cpuexecutioncap = "90"
server_cpus            = 4

nginx_port            = "80"
varnish_port          = "5580"

nodejs_version        = "latest"   # By default "latest" will equal the latest stable version
nodejs_packages       = []         # List any global NodeJS packages that you want to install

ruby_version          = "2.1.1"

# Lets do this
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

# Which box are we using?
config.vm.box = "centos-65-x64-virtualbox-nocm"
config.vm.box_url = "http://puppet-vagrant-boxes.puppetlabs.com/centos-65-x64-virtualbox-nocm.box"

# Network settings
config.vm.hostname = "vagrant"
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: server_ip

# Port forwarding
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 35729, host: 35729 #LiveReload
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8081 #HTTP

# Folder sharing
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant"
#    id: "core",
#    type: "nfs",
#    :mount_options => ['nolock,vers=3,udp,noatime']

# Virtualbox settings
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|

# Set memory
vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", server_memory]

# Trying to speed things up a bit http://www.adrikodde.nl/blog/2013/tips-debug-slow-vagrant-box/
vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpuexecutioncap", server_cpuexecutioncap]
vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", server_cpus]

# Set the timesync threshold to 10 seconds, instead of the default 20 minutes.
# If the clock gets more than 15 minutes out of sync (due to your laptop going
# to sleep for instance, then some 3rd party services will reject requests.
vb.customize ["guestproperty", "set", :id, "/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/VBoxService/--timesync-set-threshold", 10000]
# Prevent VMs running on Ubuntu to lose internet connection
vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnsproxy1", "on"]

end

# Configure cached packages to be shared between instances of the same base box.
# More info on http://fgrehm.viewdocs.io/vagrant-cachier/usage
if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-cachier")
config.cache.scope = :box
end

# Provision Base Packages
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "#{github_path}scripts/base.sh"

# Provision PHP 5.4
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "#{github_path}scripts/php54.sh"

# Install Nodejs
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "#{github_path}scripts/nodejs.sh", privileged: false, args: nodejs_packages.unshift(nodejs_version)

# Install rbenv
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "#{github_path}scripts/rbenv.sh", privileged: false, args: ruby_version

# Provision Nginx
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "#{github_path}scripts/nginx.sh", args: [server_ip, nginx_port]

# Provision MariaDB
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "#{github_path}scripts/mariadb55.sh"

# Install AMQP
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "#{github_path}scripts/amqp.sh"

# Install APC
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "#{github_path}scripts/apc.sh"

# Install RabbitMQ
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "#{github_path}scripts/rabbitmq.sh"

# Install Supervisord
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "#{github_path}scripts/supervisord.sh"

# Install Phantomjs
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "#{github_path}scripts/phantomjs.sh"

# Install Varnish
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "#{github_path}scripts/varnish.sh", args: [server_ip, nginx_port, varnish_port]

# Install fonts
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "#{github_path}scripts/fonts.sh"

# Finalise install
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "#{github_path}scripts/finalise.sh", privileged: false

end
```